# How to add rows to gridview dynamically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a textbox, which accepts a numeric field. Depending on value in this textbox that number of rows are appended to `GridView` (first column contains label and second column contains textbox control).

How to do this?

Comment: I assume that you've [google it](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=How+to+add+rows+to+gridview+dynamically+in+asp.net), have you? Even on the right side of this question you'll find lot of related questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gridview dynamically add new row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511974/gridview-dynamically-add-new-row)